# Java Extended Class Accessor

Tags: java, extends

Is there a way to access a `private` field in a parent class from a subclass?
ie:

```
public class parent<T> {
    private int MaxSize; 

    ...

}

public class sub extends parent {
    public int getMaxSize() {
        return MaxSize;
    }
}
```

Basically i want an accessor method, `getMaxSize()`, to return the maximum size of an `ArrayQueue`. Thanks.

Comment: It wouldn't be very private, then, would it. You can create an accessor method, make it protected, use reflection (ew), etc.

Comment: Any reason why an object of type `parent` shouldn't have that `getMaxSize()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - `private` fields can only be directly accessed within the class in which they are declared. You could make the field `protected`, however, which would allow you to access it from subclasses. The table below is a handy reference:

```
Access permitted by each moodier:

Modifier    Class   Package   Subclass   World
----------------------------------------------
public       Y       Y         Y          Y
protected    Y       Y         Y          N
no modifier  Y       Y         N          N
private      Y       N         N          N
```

[[**source**]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Of course you can also write a `public` (or `protected`!) getter method which would just return the value of your field, and use this method in the subclass instead of the actual field itself.

Just as an aside, it is convention to write variable names in *camelCase* in Java, i.e. `maxSize`.

Answer (score 1):

`private` variables cannot be accessed from any class other than their declaring class, meaning that subclasses do not have access to `private` variables of their parent.

You can add a getter in your parent class with `public` access, which both allow the subclass access.  With this structure, your subclass with also inherit `getMaxSize()` from the parent, removing the need to declare the method in the subclass.

```
public class Parent {
    private int maxSize;

    public int getMaxSize() {
        return maxSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: now all you need to add to use Vukan's answer is super.getMaxSize(); or this.getMaxSize();